# How to train and update weights of filters

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, backpropagation

I have some problems with training CNN :(

For example:
Input 6x6x3, 1 core 3x3x3, output = 4x4x1 => pool: 2x2x1

[image]
By backpropagation I calculated deltas for output.

[This tutor](https://www.jefkine.com/general/2016/09/05/backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks/) and other tutors are explain to calc deltas for weights and Input only for 2D:

input*output=deltas for 2D weights

filter*out = input delta

**But how I can to calc weights deltas for 3D filters?**

**I must to multiply each input by output as below?**

FilterLayer1Delta = OutputDelta * InputLayer1 **?**

FilterLayer2Delta = OutputDelta * InputLayer2 **?**

FilterLayer3Delta = OutputDelta * InputLayer3 **?**